# Is there notation to express multiplying a set by a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

I have a set of vectors $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_N\}$ where I multiply each vector with the same matrix $M$, resulting in a new set with the computed $N$ vectors, e.g., $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_N\}$ "*some operator*" $M = \{b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_N\}$. Is there a symbol or other notation to denote this (in place of "*some operator*")? Or would I have to use pseudocode, e.g., "For each," to describe this calculation?

Comment: Do you really want to do the operation on a *set*? Suppose that $M = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}$, while $a_1 = \pmatrix{1\\0}$ and $a_2 = \pmatrix{1\\1}$. Do you want $M\cdot \{ a_1, a_2 \}$ to have two elements or one? Because the vectors $Ma_1$ and $Ma_2$ are equal, so if you take a set containing both, it'll be a one-element set. My guess is that you really want to talk about sequences (possibly ordered) or lists or tuples of vectors, in which case assembling the $a_i$s into a matrix as @RSerrao suggests in the third bullet below is surely a good way to go.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm confused on something. If $a_1$ and $a_2$ are different, then how can $Ma_1$ and $Ma_2$ be the same?

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying now. Good point.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to form a matrix $A=[a_1 ~a_2~ \dots~ a_n]$ from your set of vectors. Then the columns of the matrix product $MA = [Ma_1 ~ Ma_2 ~\dots~M a_n]$ will precisely recover the matrix $M$ times each vector individually.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything like what you ask for, the closest I can think of would be one of: (using $M$ to denote the matrix)

- $\{Ma_1, Ma_2, \cdots, Ma_N\}$
- $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^N,\ \ b_i = Ma_i$
- If you take $A$, a matrix whose $i$th column is $a_i$, you can also think of the columns of $MA$ to be the $b_i$.